# Program is not stepping into the Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

Functions in Thread are not working. Tested with debugging mode where the program just skips stepping into the Thread expression. In my case "ThreadStart action = ()=>{...", please see more as follows,

```
      DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(srcFile);
        FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles(name +  ".pdf").OrderByDescending(n => n.Name).ToArray(); 
           if (files.Length == 0) { return; }              
            foreach (FileInfo t in files)
            {
                _queue.Enqueue(t.Name);  //Insert files in to the concurrent queue.        

                    ThreadStart action = () =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            _semaphore.WaitOne();  // Semaphore 
                            string qfile;
                            while (_queue.TryPeek(out qfile))
                            {  
                              string srcFile = srcPath + "\\" + qfile;
                              string desFile = desPath + "\\" + qfile);

                                MoveFil(srcFile, desFile);    
                                PrintReport(desFile); 
                                _queue.TryDequeue(out qfile);
                            }                                    
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Moving and Printing error: " +                              
                                             e.Message);                                
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            _semaphore.Release();
                        }
                    };
                    Thread thread = new Thread(action);
                    thread.Start();
                }

     private void PrintReport(string filePrint)
      {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.Verb = "print";
            info.FileName = filePrint;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;                

            Process p = Process.Start(info);
            p.CloseMainWindow();
            if (!p.HasExited) Thread.Sleep(5000);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Encounted a problem while printing! "+                                
                             e.Message);

        }
    }
```

Comment: So, you are creating a separate thread for each file, but within the thread you are calling `semaphore.WaitOne()` and realease it only, when the thread has finished. So in fact, you are serializing your threads to work one after the other. You don't need threads for that. If you can process two files at the same time, you don't need the semaphore, if you can't you don't need threads ...

Comment: As for your problem with debugging: Did you try to set a breakpoint within the threaded code (for instance at `semphore.WaitOne()` and see if this breakpoint is hit? If you just step through the debugger won't change into another thread. Furthermore `ThreadStart action = () => ... ` is just an assignment. The code of the action is not executed yet. It will only be executed after `Thread.Start()`

Comment: And a third thing i noticed: you use `TryPeek()` for getting the first element of the queue. But this won't remove the element from the queue. (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267308(v=vs.110).aspx)  )The first thread entering the semaphore will process the first file in the queue over and over again without ever finishing. Any other thread will be locked out by the semaphore ...

Comment: And if you really want several threads to do the same, you don't need a new `ThreadStart` in each iteration of the for loop, but you can define it before you enter the loop and just create new threads. And I would strongly suggest, you check, which operations you can do in parallel and which don't. (For instance moving multiple files in parallel might work, printing multiple reports won't) and just synchronize the sections which need to be executed in serial

Comment: I actually need to print and move each file in a queue. You got the point what I really want to do. I need one process at a time. That means when one file is finished it will turn for the another one.

Comment: I even tried with... "Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{....});", but it didn't work either.

Comment: You don't need neither threads nor queues for that. Just do it like this `foreach (var f in files) { String s = ..., t = ...; MoveFile(s, t); PrintReport(t); }`

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint at `semaphore.WaitOne()`? See my third comment, why all other threads won't be able to pass this line.

Comment: Forgot to write, I used TryDequeue... se edited code

Comment: I tested without thread and queues, but my requirement is to follow file sequences. Because file sequences doesn't follow during printing process.

Comment: Actually, I put break-point at semaphore.WaitOne(), the whole Thread expression avoided while debugging... It happened one in my case..

Comment: But, now whenever I run it works as I expect. But, the main problem in production dept. Whenever they run functions inside the Thread don't work.. In my case, Move and print functions does't work for them. Could not find the reason!

Comment: Actually, with your code, the chances are very high, that the first thread entering the semaphore, does all the work. Because as long as one thread entered the critical section, it does not leave until the queue is empty. And probably iterating over a `FileInfo[]` will take less time than moving and printing files.

Comment: I've tested in several machines, running program and running .exe file. Always works for me as I expected, but move and print doesn't work for them. Does it depends on Windows versions?

Comment: Yes, that can be the problem since printing process takes longer that the iteration.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "file sequences", but the way your code is written, it does not use any of the advantages of threads and queues. The files are processed one after the other in exactly the order you get them from GetFiles. So if you want to be on the safe side, use the code template I showed you above. It does exactly the same as your code.

Comment: You are aware that your breakpoint at semaphore.WaitOne() will only be hit AFTER the thread has been started with `thread.Start()`, aren't you?

Comment: At the beginning, I tried the same as you showed.But, during printing queue sequences can't follow. For example, I need to print first array first and then second and so on. But, the output of printing page doesn't follow the queue, Simply I need to print 1,2,3 in the queue. But, printing page comes sometimes, 2,1,3 and sometimes, 1,3,2 etc.

Comment: But, I tried using Task.. For example, Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{ _semaphore,WaitOne(); .... MoveFile(src, des), PrintFile(des.) }); Move and print didn't work either.

Comment: No. That cannot happen if you process the files one after the other in a simple for loop! `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` delivers the files in alphabetical order. If you process the array in that order, there is no way the printing get shuffled, unless you do something strange in `PrintReport()`

Comment: As I said it is working for me. Hitting breakpoint at _semaphonre(), move()..whereever. But, in production dept. when they run .exe file, move and print doesn't work. In order to find the reason I setted log file just outside (before) and inside the Thread. Did result outside the Thread, but didn't get any text inside The thread.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but didn't write the whole code, it is actually like this. FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles(name + ".pdf").OrderByDescending(n => n.Name).ToArray();

Comment: Are you sure there are files to process? If directory.GetFiles returns nothing, then none of your code gets executed. I must insist, like @derpirscher that you should take out your threading code, because as it is it's only adding complexity and providing you no benefit.

Comment: For the last time: You don't need threads and queues. If Moving and Printing doesn't work in your production environment it does not have anything to do with threading, but maybe the way those methods are coded. And it surely does not matter, whether the files are sorted ascending or descending. In fact, you don't even do any threading in the moment. You surely create a lot of threads. But they don't run in parallel and I'm 99% sure only one of them does all the work. All other just will see an empty queue.

Comment: I didn't write the whole code, but, I edited a bit. Please see the code above. Yes, I'll try like you suggested,

Comment: @derpirscher: As I said everything worked without Thread and queue. But, using process.start(), printing pdf file didn't follow first come first out, that is why I used Threading and queue.

Comment: But, The question is, current code provides all requirements, why not working at production environment? Is there needed something change in there windows settings ?

Comment: The code you provide does not compile. What is the variable "name"? I think it's filtering out your files and that's why nothing gets executed in production. To be clear, your queueing and threading have nothing to do with your problem. The fact that your printing came in the wrong order comes from another bug in your code.

Comment: You reuse the variable name srcFile in your DirectoryInfo and in your inner loop. This also does not compile. Please provide a code sample that compiles.

Comment: Yes, 'name' is a string type. One more thing for using Threading is that without using Threading the program blocks UI while printing because in PrintReport(desFile) function I used Thread.sleep(5000).

Comment: I know it's a string, I'm asking where it comes from. It filters the files you get from GetFiles, so it's possible that it filters out all the files in production, which is why nothing happens.

Comment: Why are you sleeping the thread?

Comment: You said you use `process.start()` for printing. Do you wait for this process to finish, before you move on to the next file. As I said before: The error possibly is in the code you don't show us ...

Comment: name is coming from another function, the program will search for matching file from directory as 'name'.

Comment: Process p = Process.Start(info);              
  if (!p.HasExited) Thread.Sleep(6000);

Comment: If I don't use Thread.Sleep. .pdf file printing page sequence doesn't come as I expected since some .pdf file takes longer time and some takes short time.

Comment: Process p = Process.Start(info);
                p.CloseMainWindow();
                if (!p.HasExited) Thread.Sleep(6000);

Comment: Please post your full PrintReport code. I suspect that is your problem all along.

Comment: Posted full PrintReport() code

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using?

Comment: Why not use the `Process.WaitForExit()`? There is no guarantee that your process will be finished after 5 seconds ... Although I suppose, print just enqueues the job in the printer queue and exists. This may in fact lead to problems: If you only wait for 5 secs, the process may not be finished yet (if a big file is to be printed), and you start enqueuing the next file. If this is rather small, it may infact start printing before the big one ... But that's just a wild guess. You should in any case, wait until the process really has exited.

Comment: This is probably your problem. p.CloseMainWindow can terminate the process before it's done, so you are not leaving the process enough time to send the print command. Use WaitForExit. I will now work on a code sample that has both WaitForExit and does not freeze the UI.

Comment: @Guillaume, Tested using WaitForExit(5000) many times. I swear, Expected file printing sequence didn't come...

Comment: The sleep is not the problem. The problem is that you close the window immediately after starting the process. This will behave differently on different computers, depending on how fast the OS can start and service new processes. Do not close the window, do not sleep. Just wait for the process to finish, that way you are sure that everything is fine, on any computer. Or, like @derpirscher , maybe the problem is that it takes more than 5 seconds on your production machines, and you are enqueuing faster than your printer can print. Either way, use WaitForExit. I updated my answer.

Comment: But, only WaitForExit() waits until I exit Acrobat Reader manually.. That should be automatically closed.

Comment: I am using .net 4.6

Comment: I'm guessing you use Acrobat Reader when debugging, but your production machines print directly to the printer without Acrobat Reader, right? This is why you see a different pattern between your development machine and the production environment. Setup your machine like the production to print directly, and you won't have to close any window, and you will see your problem.

Comment: Good, my updated answer will work with .Net 4.6. Give it a try.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR, Actually, they are running with Acrobat Reader, that's why I  have to run the test with Acrobat Reader.

Comment: I am going to test you suggested.. Lets see...Coming back with the result :D

Comment: I now understand why you close the window. I guess you can try to call p.CloseMainWindow *before* you call p.WaitForExit, but I don't know if it will work properly. If it doesn't work, you can try the /h argument for Acrobat Reader to make sure the window is minimized. If *that* doesn't work, then I'm all out of ideas :P

Comment: Actually, they don't have to see the report on the screen. They just have to print the report.with required sequence. For example, if name= "2017-07-11", it will look for pdf file which is this date, but pdf file name won't be the same. It can be "HLP2017-07-11.pdf", "GKN2017-07-11.pdf", "TYP2017-07-11.pdf". Here, the requirement is, print the file where the files first alphabet started with 'T' then 'H' and then 'G', that is why I used FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles(name + ".pdf").OrderByDescending(n => n.Name).ToArray();

Comment: But, during printing, the process can't maintain the order, even WaitForExit() can't help. That is why used if (!p.HasExited) Thread.Sleep(6000); But, it blocks the UI, and that is the reason using seperate threading.

Comment: To maintain the order, you should wait until a file is completely queued in the windows printer queue, ie Acrobat Reader has finished printing before you can queue the next file. The problem is : There is no way to get this information, because Acrobat Reader won't exit by itself. So the only thing you can do is waiting for some reasonable amout of time before you try to exit the process. I don't know, how Acrobat reacts on a `CloseMainWindow` while printing. Maybe it cancels the job completely, maybe it just aborts admidst, maybe it even ignores the signal

Comment: You could also try to wait a few seconds BEFORE you call `CloseMainWindow()`. And maybe you could increase the timespan

Comment: A complete different approach would be the following: Use some pdf library to merge  all your documents in your desired order into a single temporary pdf and then you only have to print one document.

Comment: @derpirscher, That is the best idea i thought. But, lack of merging knowledge just avoided this.

Comment: Just search for merge PDF here, there are numerous easy examples!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ask the debugger to step over the line that starts with "ThreadAction action = () ...", you are declaring the code that will execute in the thread. You are not executing it yet. The debugger steps over the full line because it's not at this point that the code executes, it's when you call "thread.Start()". However the debugger does not know that thread.Start begins executing the code in your action, so it just steps over that line as well.

In order to step through the code in your thread, you must set a breakpoint inside your action code. Stepping over will not work.

edit: It looks like all your threads are waiting on a semaphore. There's no point in doing this. Either your code is asynchronous, in which case it does not need a semaphore, or it's synchronous, in which case it does not need threads.

edit2: It seems your is not due to multithreading. Here is a code sample that uses async/await to perform blocking operations without freezing your UI. Note that you must call NotMulthreading like this:

```
await NotMultithreading();
```

And every function that calls NotMultithreading must be marked async, all the way up to your button handler.

```
public async Task NotMultithreading(string name, string srcPath, string desPath)
{
    //Your code sample used this line
    //DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(srcFile);
    //But I suspect you should use srcPath, which is probably your bug.
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(srcPath);
    FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles(name + ".pdf");
    foreach (FileInfo t in files)
    {
        try
        {
            var desFile = Path.Combine(desPath, t.Name);
            t.MoveTo(desFile);
            await PrintReport(desFile);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Moving and Printing error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}

private Task PrintReport(string filePrint)
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.Verb = "print";
    info.FileName = filePrint;
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Process p = Process.Start(info);
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Encounted a problem while printing! " +
                                e.Message);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Getting an error at "await PrintReport(desFile)", is that 'Task does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' cold be found... and at return Task.Run....'Task ' doesn't contain a definitaion for 'Run'

Comment: @RRah This seems to be a problem with your .Net version. You told me you use 4.6, but Google tells me this error happens when you use .Net version below 4.5.